# Where to store ODP.NET Managed Driver Connection Strings?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, odp.net, odp.net-managed

Finally got ODP.NET configured and the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess DLL referenced in the project.

I was testing with a TNS connection in the code behind in a WPF project (see below).

This question is probably elementary, but I can't find any good information on this, as all examples/jump-starts show embedding the connection string like this.

Is there a better (more common) way to store the connection string for ODP.NET to make it easier to maintain (i.e. it should be a configuration change that doesn't require completely rebuilding the code if it should change)?  For example, similar to storing in app.config for SQL Server and IIS?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;


namespace TEST
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private OracleConnection con;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            try
            {
                con = new OracleConnection("User Id=*****; Password=******; Data Source=******");
                con.Open();


            }
            catch (OracleException oracleErr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(oracleErr.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't your app just read the app.config (or another config file) to get this value? A quick googling pulls up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/89211k9b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254494%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In case you used the tnsnames.ora from the Oracle Client for the unmanaged version then for the managed version you just have to copy the tnsnames to your project directory.